# vue.js how do I bind a class on click to a list item created by v-for utilising a template component?

Tags: javascript, class, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to apply an active class to a list item in a template component when it is clicked upon, this should be exclusive and remove the class from all other list items.

I have tried passing through a new data object on click and referencing that, I have even used the example in the official documentation to no avail, I have no idea why it isn't working.

```js
Vue.component('delivery-options', {
      props: ['deliveries'],
      template: '<li><p><strong>{{ deliveries.price }}</strong>{{ deliveries.title }}</p><p>{{ deliveries.desc }}</p></li>'
    })
    Vue.component('ledger', {
      props: ['values'],
      template: '<li><p>{{ values.title }}<span>{{ values.price }}</span></p></li>'
    })
    var checkout = new Vue({
      el: '#checkout-app',
      data: {
        deliveryList: [
          { id: 0, price: '£3.99 ', title: 'Home delivery', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' },
          { id: 1, price: 'Free ', title: 'Store collection', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' },
          { id: 2, price: '£5.99 ', title: 'Precise delivery', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' }
        ],
        valuesList: [
          { id: 0, price: '£1233.99', title: 'Order value', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' },
          { id: 1, price: '£3.99', title: 'Delivery', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' },
          { id: 2, price: '£5.99', title: 'Total', desc: 'Your total including delivery.' }
        ]
      }
    })
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.delivery-options li {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ledger {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="checkout-app">
    <ul class="delivery-options">
      <delivery-options
        v-for="option in deliveryList"
        v-bind:deliveries="option"
        v-bind:key="option.id">
      </delivery-options>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ledger">
      <ledger
        v-for="value in valuesList"
        v-bind:values="value"
        v-bind:key="value.id">
      </ledger>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to do something like this:

```js
console.clear()

Vue.component('delivery-options', {
      props: ['deliveries', "isActive"],
      template: `<li @click="$emit('set-active', deliveries)" :class="{active: isActive}"><p><strong>{{ deliveries.price }}</strong>{{ deliveries.title }}</p><p>{{ deliveries.desc }}</p></li>`
    })
    Vue.component('ledger', {
      props: ['values'],
      template: '<li><p>{{ values.title }}<span>{{ values.price }}</span></p></li>'
    })
    var checkout = new Vue({
      el: '#checkout-app',
      data: {
        activeDelivery: null,
        deliveryList: [
          { id: 0, price: '£3.99 ', title: 'Home delivery', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' },
          { id: 1, price: 'Free ', title: 'Store collection', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' },
          { id: 2, price: '£5.99 ', title: 'Precise delivery', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' }
        ],
        valuesList: [
          { id: 0, price: '£1233.99', title: 'Order value', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' },
          { id: 1, price: '£3.99', title: 'Delivery', desc: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' },
          { id: 2, price: '£5.99', title: 'Total', desc: 'Your total including delivery.' }
        ]
      },
    })
```

```css
ul {
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.delivery-options li {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.ledger {
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 1rem;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.active {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="checkout-app">
    <ul class="delivery-options">
      <delivery-options
        v-for="option in deliveryList"
        v-bind:deliveries="option"
        v-bind:key="option.id"
        v-bind:is-active="option === activeDelivery"
        v-on:set-active="v => activeDelivery = v">
      </delivery-options>
    </ul>
    <ul class="ledger">
      <ledger
        v-for="value in valuesList"
        v-bind:values="value"
        v-bind:key="value.id">
      </ledger>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Basically, track which delivery is active using a data property, then set the class in the component based on whether it is the active delivery or not. In order to set the active delivery on click, the component needs to emit an event letting the parent know which delivery was clicked.

Comment: amazing thank you, I had something similar before but it was only tracking clicks on the parent, therefore it wasn't actually updating anything at all